# passing data from android to php by params

Tags: php, android, database, parameter-passing

I passing data from android to php by params buy
I cant receive my table name?

in activity :

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("enname",objectShohada.getEnname());
    MyHttpClient.get("Loaderimages.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

            list.clear();
            ObjectShohada[] tempList = new Gson().fromJson(new String(responseBody), ObjectShohada[].class);
            list.addAll(Arrays.asList(tempList));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //app.l(statusCode+"");

        }
```

in php :

```
$name = $_REQUEST[$parms["enname"]];

$query = "SELECT * FROM '$name'";
```

Comment: `$name = $_REQUEST[$parms["enname"]];` - What is `$parms`? Did you try just `$_GET['enname']`?

Comment: yes : $name = $_GET['enname']; : but I faced this error
Notice: Undefined index: enname in C:\xampp\htdocs\sh\Loaderimages.php on line 6